# How to set up alias for a custom package?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

Can't set up an alias for a custom package. I'm using the Visual Studio Code.
My imports looks like this

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "structute-test/util"
    "time"
)
```

But when I try to insert the alias like

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    ut "structute-test/util"
    "time"
)
```

then the Visual Studio Code just hide the custom alias name so it looks like in the fist code snipet. What is wrong with a such definition?

Comment: It's your code formatter that removes the deprecated package alias

Comment: @TheophileDano so using the aliases are deprecated?

Comment: Not really, but it's not considered *good* practice. Why do you want to write `ut` in place of `util` ?

Comment: @TheophileDano well it's just a sample and if the package would be long names then aliases are usefull

Comment: No because you wouldn't create packages with long names

Comment: Have you tried to actually use the alias in the code? The Go plugin probably removes the alias because you don't use it.

Comment: "ut" is not an alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most probable reason why it removes your alias is that you use "util" in the .go file but you don't use the "ut" alias. Using "ut" alias in the file should prevent it from being removed.